# Code using verbatim doesn't work when copied back in a text editor

Tags: verbatim, code, octave

I'm trying to use `verbatim` to copy the implementation of an algorithm written in `octave`. For this I introduced the following lines in latex

```
\begin{verbatim}
F = @(z) [z(1) + 2*z(2) - 2; 2*z(2)*z(3)^2 - 2/3; 2*z(2)*z(3)^4 - 2/5];
\end{verbatim}
```

That generates in return a piece of code on a pdf document. However when I copy back the code from the generated pdf to a text editor, the code doesn't work because the exponential sign `^` copied into the text editor differs from the original code written in the text editor. The proof that this is the problem is that when I erase and rewrite the `^` sign from the copied chunk of code, the code works.

How is it possible to fix the problem? Because the goal of function like `verbatim` is to have ready to use code when copying from a latex document and not having to extra edit it when before running it.

**EDIT**

I generated the following new `.tex` file and it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Questions}
\begin{verbatim}
F = @(z) [z(1) + 2*z(2) - 2; 2*z(2)*z(3)^2 - 2/3; 2*z(2)*z(3)^4 - 2/5];
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

How come doesn't it work in my principal `.tex` file? Is it possible that it comes from all the packages that I'm using?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Maybe the `listings` package could be an alternative

Comment: Thank you for your comment @samcarter. I edited the question after your comment. I already tried `listings` previously and it made the problem even worse: on top of the problem with exponential `^` sign, also present in `listings`, there was the same problem with multiplication `*`sign which wasn't recognized on the text editor

Comment: Can you make a MWE that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `times` package (which is obsolete) by the `mathptmx` package, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Many thanks @EricMarsden. That solved the problem!