# executable code containing symbol `'` inserted with verbatim on pdf. Error while copying back into a text editor

Tags: verbatim, code, octave

I'm trying to insert Octave code in a pdf. However, there is a problem with the sign `'` (which means transposition in Octave code). However when I copy the code from the generated pdf, the code doesn't run:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan,
}

\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{calrsfs}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}
\title{Math notes}
\author{Eric Buffle}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents{}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{240,248,255}
\begin{shaded}
\begin{verbatim}
% BeamStretch
EA=1.0; L=3; F=0.2; N=20; h = L/(N+1); % stepsize
x = (h:h:L)';
f = zeros(size(x)); % f(x) = 0
g = h^2/EA*f ; g(N+1) = g(N+1)/2+h*F/EA;
%% build the triadiagonal , symmetric matrix
di = 2*ones(N+1,1); di(N+1) = 1; % diagonal
up = -ones(N,1); % upper and lower diagonal
u = trisolve(di,up,g); plot ([0;x] ,[0;u])
\end{verbatim}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> x = (h:h:L)’;
               ^

error: 'x' undefined near line 1 column 16
error: 'f' undefined near line 1 column 12
error: 'g' undefined near line 1 column 20
```

I also tried to comment out `\usepackage{mathptmx}` but the problem persisted
I recently posted a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458310/code-using-verbatim-doesnt-work-when-copied-back-in-a-text-editor) but I still couldn't find a solution to the problem

Comment: For an MWE you shouldn't include all unnecessary package. BTW, you load `framed` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `verbatim` handling the single quote.
If you load `\usepackage{upquote}` in the preamble, the `'` will be compiled as `'`. Otherwise, it's compiled as `’`, a different character.

Note that I removed packages and lines that are not strictly neccessary for illustrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
% BeamStretch
EA=1.0; L=3; F=0.2; N=20; h = L/(N+1); % stepsize
x = (h:h:L)';
f = zeros(size(x)); % f(x) = 0
g = h^2/EA*f ; g(N+1) = g(N+1)/2+h*F/EA;
%% build the triadiagonal , symmetric matrix
di = 2*ones(N+1,1); di(N+1) = 1; % diagonal
up = -ones(N,1); % upper and lower diagonal
u = trisolve(di,up,g); plot ([0;x] ,[0;u])
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```