# executable code containing symbol `^` inserted with verbatim on pdf. Error while copying back into a text editor

Tags: fonts, symbols, code, octave

I'm trying to insert Octave code in a pdf containing the character `^`. However when I copy the code from the generated pdf, the code doesn't run: The I already posted [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459378/executable-code-containing-symbol-inserted-with-verbatim-on-pdf-error-while) and could solve the problem. However the problem reappeared. I suspect one of the loaded package is responsible.

Here is an example of code with the loaded packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{calrsfs}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}
\title{Notes}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents{}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{240,248,255}
\begin{shaded}
    \begin{verbatim}
x^2
    \end{verbatim}
\end{shaded}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Code produced by a listing is not necessarily meant to run and one shouldn't expect it to after just copy&pasting it.

Comment: indeed when copying pasting from PDF I get the MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT U+02C6 (letter `ˆ`) and not the usual ascii caret. Culprit is `lmodern` package. But add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and it should fix the issue.

Comment: MWE: simply load lmodern and consider `\texttt{x\string^2}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you may be interested into this why does `\OT1/lmtt/m/n/10 ^` give a `ˆ` in PDF (or at least when copying back from PDF, tested with Skim on mac os x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing this as a provisory answer to give a workaround awaiting the fonts expert (... or experts).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\texttt{x\string^2}
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

Uncomment the `fontenc` line to fix the issue. Then copy-pasting from PDF gives a normal ascii caret, not a MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT U+02C6 (letter `ˆ`)